# Nested Generics

Tags: java, generics

I got several classes:

Standard classes:

**WorkflowGraphModel:**

```
public class WorkflowGraphModel<T> implements IWorkflowGraphModel<T>

public WorkflowGraphModel( List<IWorkflowGraphEntry<T>> entries ) 
{
  this.entries = entries;
}
```

**WorkflowGraphEntry:**

```
public class WorkflowGraphEntry<T> implements IWorkflowGraphEntry<T>
```

Special implementations:

**ApprovalStepGraphEntry**

```
public class ApprovalStepGraphEntry extends WorkflowGraphEntry<ApprovalStep>
```

**ApprovalStepGraphModel**

```
public class ApprovalStepGraphModel extends WorkflowGraphModel<ApprovalStepGraphEntry>

public ApprovalStepGraphModel( List<ApprovalStepGraphEntry> stepEntries )
{
  super( stepEntries );
}
```

There is an error when calling

```
super( stepEntries );
```

WorkflowGraphModel (java.util.List>)
in `WorkflowGraphModel` cannot be applied to (java.util.List)

I don't know why the compiler doesn't know that `ApprovalStepGraphEntry` implements `IWorkflowGraphEntry`. In my opinion the generics are well set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type `List <IWorkflowGraphEntry <ApprovalStep>>` is not assignable from `List <ApprovalStepGraphEntry>`.  You should probably change `List <IWorkflowGraphEntry <ApprovalStep>>` to `List<? extends IWorkflowGraphEntry <ApprovalStep>>` or something like this.

Here is an explanation why types mentioned above are not compatible.  Lets consider we have:

```
interface A {...}
class B extends A {...}
class B1 extends A {...}
interface C <T> {public void set (T t);}
```

Then the following is incorrect:

```
C <A> ca;
C <B> cb = ...;
ca = cb; // Error here
ca.set (new B1 ()); // Correct!
```

Note that once `ca` is declared as `C <A> ca`, method `ca.set` accepts parameter of type `A` thus `new B1()` is valid value for it.  At the same time, method `cb.set` accepts parameter of type `B`, and thus `new B1()` is not a valid value for this parameter.  If we would be able to assign `cb` to `ca`, then we would be able to later call `ca.set (new B1())` which will pass value of invalid type to the set method.  To prevent such situations, compiler treats `C <A>` and `C <B>` types as incompatible even when `A` and `B` are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ApprovalStepGraphEntry` does not implement `IWorkflowGraphEntry`, it extends `WorkflowGraphEntry`, which in turn implements the interface. You need to make this distinction clear when defining the generic type:

Instead of

```
public WorkflowGraphModel( List<IWorkflowGraphEntry<T>> entries )
```

You need

```
public WorkflowGraphModel( List<? extends IWorkflowGraphEntry<T>> entries )
```

Comment: I also thank you! I thought the compiler would check if WorkflowGraphEntry implements IWorkflowGraphEntry.